# Using C#, how to get one cell text from edited row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hy,

I have a gridView control in Asp.NET like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="outputGridView" runat="server" onrowediting="OutputGridView_RowEditing">
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                        ItemStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="JobId" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#e1e1e1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("JobId")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="250px" BorderWidth="1px"
                            BorderColor="#e1e1e1"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

</aspGridView>
```

On OutputGridView_RowEditing I have this code:

```
protected void OutputGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow currentRow = outputGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
            string JobId = currentRow.Cells[2].Text;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

But in 'JobId' string its "", does anyone have any idea how can I get the text of the third cell from the row that is being edited?

Thank you,

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what Bonshington said is correct, accept you want to add an id to the label.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="LblJobId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobId") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>

protected void OutputGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow currentRow = outputGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    Label jobIdLabel = (Label)currentRow.Cells[2].FindControl("LblJobId");
    string jobId = jobIdLabel.Text;
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Bind() method instead of Eval() method, it is for evaluation purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

try to put it in literal cotnrol

```
<label><%# Eval("JobId")%></label>
```

and your jobID column will positioned as cell's child control

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get    `GridViewRow currentRow`  you have to use

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate><asp:Label id="lbl" Text="<%# Eval("JobId")%>" /></EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Auto-generated grid columns use `Cells` property

```
 protected void OutputGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
     OutputGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0]
 }
```

Comment: i just change my answer, you do not need e.Row.RowType. The row that you want to edit is a valid row type.